# Text widget doesn't save the content

Tags: widgets, widget-text

I am trying to save data in the default text widget. But when I click save, all the data are not saving and the field becomes empty.
It happens when I edit in title field or text field.

[image]

As I new to WordPress, I don't know the solution. I haven't installed any cache plugins. I haven't done any changes in functions.php or anywhere.

Comment: I'm having this issue too, super strange. Can't even save a single letter in the Title, Visual or Text fields.

Comment: Do you have Jetpack active? If so, the issue may be related to a bug in the 5.2 release: https://jetpack.com/2017/08/02/jetpack-5-2-1-fixes-a-sidebar-widget-bug/

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this.

Step  1:

```
Go to Appearence --> Widgets
```

Step 2:

```
Then at the top right of the screen you should see a tab that says Screen Options. Click on that, then a link will appear in the top left of your screen that says ‘Enable Accessibility Mode’ and click on that and give it a try.
```

i hope is useful

Comment: Didn't help me at all, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but recently I had a similar problem (WordPress 5.3) and the solution was to enable Accessibility Mode (top-right corner).